# explode string into variables

Tags: php

Is there a way to explode a string into variables e.g

```
some_function($min, $max, "3, 20");
```

such that $min is assigned the value 3 and $max is assigned the value 20.

I know I can simply use

```
$data = explode("3, 20");
```

just wondering if there is another way.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

PHP's language construct [`list()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) can perform multiple assignments to variables (or even other array keys) by assigning an array.

```
list($min, $max) = explode(",", "3,20");
```

However, you would still need to apply a `trim()` to your variables since the `$max` value would have a leading space, or replace `explode()` with `preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $string)` to split it on commas and surrounding whitespace.

**Note:** Use caution with `list()` to be sure that the array you're assigning contains the same number of elements as `list()` has variables.

In **PHP 5.x**, when assigning a value directly to another array, as an element of that array, `list()` values are assigned from right to left in PHP 5.x, not left to right. In other words, you'll end up with array that is populated backwards (last value, first).

https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php

In **PHP 7.x** `list()` arguments are assigned from left to right, when assigning elements directly to an array. In other words, you'll end up with the first value as the first element in the recipient array.

> ```
> <?php
>     list($a[], $a[], $a[]) = [1, 2, 3];
>     var_dump($a);
> ?>
> ```

[PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php)

**PHP 5.X** Last value gets the first element position, but the recipient must an array (in this case $a, is the array)!

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(3)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(1)
}
```

**PHP 7.x** First value becomes the first array element.

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
}
```

[PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php)

Comment: Technically that is the *language construct* of `list()`. But +1.

Comment: @DaveRandom I didn't say `list()` was a function, I said that's _the function of_ `list()`. Subtle, but I'll clarify anyway :)

Comment: Thanx.....i will read up on the list function, As for the note, i will use the limit parameter on the explode function. am guessing that is its function right?

Comment: @kayfun Yes that's the purpose of explode()'s limit.

Comment: Why not just set the delimiter to `", "` and skip the whole `trim()` thing

Comment: @Tom More robust to cover either case, but with more overhead would be `preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', "3, 20,   21,   35")`

Comment: True, but if the list is created on the back-end it's unnecessary to use trim if you know the layout. But yeah, I get your point. If the input may contain an unknown amount of spaces `trim()` is the way to go.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski starting PHP 7 the behavior is changed to reading variables starting left.http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

Answer (score 10):

Since **PHP 7.1** there is a new feature called

> **Symmetric array destructuring**: The shorthand array syntax ([]) may now
>   be used to destructure arrays for assignments (including within
>   foreach), as an alternative to the existing list() syntax, which is
>   still supported.

That means that you can do now:

```
[$one, $two] = explode(";", "one;two");
echo $one; // one
echo $two; // two
```

As an alternative to list(), I find it myself a very elegant and readable solution that arrived with 7.1+ ... it is the same, but better.

Note: As the quote indicates, you can use the shorthand array syntax (*[]*) to assign variables in foreach declarations, but that's not related to the question, so check it out!

Documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php